# What is the probability of someone correctly guessing the number of gumballs in a jar?

Tags: probability

Can someone explain to me how I would go about calculating / estimating how many people would guess correctly the number of gumballs in a jar?

If I set up a game in which I show 1,000 people a jar full of gumballs, so they can see the size of the jar and the individual gumballs.  I also tell them that there are definitely less than 1,000 gumballs in the jar and each person is allowed just one guess.  How do I calculate the number of people who are likely to guess correctly?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here.  If the correct answer is $10$, then everyone will guess correctly.  If the correct answer is $967$, I'd expect only a small number to be correct.

Comment: What is the actual distribution of the number?  Seeing the jar and being told the bound, what is the distribution of people's guesses?

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  However, some assumptions may be made that permit an exact computation. [1] You correctly tell people that the number of gumballs is some number chosen at random, with uniform distribution, from the set $\{1,2,\cdots, 999\}.$ [2] A towel is placed over the jar of gumballs, so that no one can  attempt to visually count/estimate the number. [3] Each person is equally likely to choose any number from $\{1,2,\cdots, 999\}$, at random.  ...see next comment

Comment: Note that this is clearly unrealistic, since the choice of (for example) numbers $\leq 200$ are (perhaps) more likely than #'s between $401$ and $600$, inclusive.  Based on these assumptions, [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) is not needed, since it is reasonable to assume that each person's guess is an independent event.  Each person has a $(1/999)$ chance of guessing correctly, so if there are $n$ people, the expected number of correct guesses $= [n \times (1/999)].$

Comment: Note further that assumption [3] from the previous comments is actually unnecessary.  Based on assumption [1], it becomes irrelevant whether (in general) people's guesses are **biased**.

Comment: An intuitive confirmation of all of this is to assume that the contest is held $(999)$ times, where each person makes the same guess on each contest, and where the *right number* is equal to $k$ for Contest-$k$.  Then, after $(999)$ contests, each of the $(n)$ people will have won exactly once.